# spark-sql: How to get the progress bar (with stages and tasks)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn, emr

How can I get a progressbar on spark-sql? spark-shell get a nice progress bar like this:
[Stage7:===========>                              (14174 + 5) / 62500]

This progressbar tells what is the total number of executors allocated, how many are running and how many completed. while the length of the progress bar indicates the % completion of the job.

Absent this we have to rely only on the Resource Manager UI and keep refreshing the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spark-sql -S` will show the condensed progress!